# strategy needed for complicated tkinter animation

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I have a python2/tkinter app where I need to code a complicated animation on a canvas after a button is clicked. By complicated, I mean that it has many stages (dozens), each stage depending on the the state of many variables set in the previous stage in ways that something like a for loop won't really manage. In pseudocode:

```
1 set a bunch of variables
2 update the canvas
3 wait a couple hundred milliseconds
4 adjust the variables
5 update the canvas (differently than before)
6 wait
```

And repeat that many times. It'd be a long function, written out. I'm struggling with the best way to code this.

1. The naive way of just putting this code in the button's callback function with calls to `time.sleep()` and the canvas draw methods won't work, of course, since the GUI thread can't be tied up that long.
2. My read on Tkinter is that it's not really thread safe, so putting this code on another thread that updates the canvas directly is asking for trouble.
3. Using the `after()` method would result in some really awkward code, where I'd have to create dozens of little functions for each stage of the animation, each of which needing access to the animation variables that would have to live outside the functions' scopes. Or possibly recode the whole thing as some kind of state machine which would also be really awkward.

Is there some other technique I'm not thinking of? Or perhaps another toolkit that's more amenable to this kind of thing?

Comment: Without concrete information about what you are actually trying to accomplish, it is very difficult to figure out what your question is, much less answer it. FWIW, I would focus on #3, and write a class to handle the animation. Making a state machine as you suggest is one of the purposes of classes, and will allow you to encapsulate the "bunch of variables" into something more manageable.

Comment: Canvas auto updates with the mainloop as far as I am aware. Even if it does not there is the `update()` method that you can use after changing the variables.

Comment: Could you use `after()` but for just one function which reads the bunch of variables off a list of tuples?